# How to pass Zig function pointers to other functions?

Tags: compiler-errors, function-pointers, zig

I have the following error when I pass in a function to another function?

```rust
const std = @import("std");

const St = struct { a: usize };

fn returnFunc(print: fn (str: []const u8, st: St) void) void {
    print("Hello", St{ .a = 1 });
}
fn toTest(str: []const u8, st: St) void {
    std.debug.print("{s}: {d}\n", .{str, st.a});
}

pub fn main() !void {
    returnFunc(toTest);
}
```

Return the following error:

```
error: parameter of type 'fn([]const u8, main.St) void' must be declared comptime
```

**Machine details:**
Zig version: 0.10.0-dev.4588+9c0d975a0
M1 Mac, MAC OS Ventura

Comment: The posted code works for me in v0.9.1. Did you try `comptime print: fn (str: []const u8, st: St) void`?

Comment: Yes. `comptime print` works! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Starting with 0.10, there are 2 ways to [pass a function as an argument](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Functions):

- As a function body. Must be `comptime`-known.
- As a function pointer.

For example:

```
const std = @import("std");

fn foo(str: []const u8) void {
    std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{ str });
}

fn asBody(comptime print: fn (str: []const u8) void) void {
    print("hello from function body");
}

fn asPointer(print: *const fn (str: []const u8) void) void {
    print("hello from function pointer");
}

pub fn main() void {
    asBody(foo);
    asPointer(foo);
}
```

This prints:

```
$ zig build run
hello from function body
hello from function pointer
```

Comment: It seems that this is one of the things that changed between v0.9.1 and v0.10.0. In v0.9.1 the `comptime` is not needed since there function values are treated as function pointers.

Comment: Indeed, you're correct. This is a 0.10 feature. On 0.9 only function pointers are available with a slightly different syntax. E.g. `fn asPointerOld(print: fn (str: []const u8) void) void { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I simply needed to change the function signature of `returnFunc` to:

```rust
fn returnFunc(comptime print: fn (str: []const u8, st: St) void) void {
    print("Hello", St{ .a = 1 });
}
```